# Get tag description and display in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, get, tags

I've tried to get the tag description and display in WordPress but with no success. I've commented below what I've added to try and get the tag description.

```
        <?php

        $q_categories = $_GET['categories'];
        $q_tags = $_GET['tags'];


            $term_id = 26;
            $taxonomy_name = 'tags';
            $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name);
            $description = tag_description(); //NOT WORKING
            foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) { 
            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name, $description );
            $tag_image = get_field('tag_image', $term);
            $show_on_landing_page = get_field('show_on_landing_page', $term);


 if ( $show_on_landing_page) { ?>

                    <div class="box three columns">
                        <div class="box-content slidedown">
                            <? if( !empty($tag_image) ): ?><img src="<? echo the_field('tag_image', $term); ?>" class="cover cat-img" /><?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="details">
                                <div class="details-container">
                                    <h4><? echo $term->name; //NOT WORKING ?></h4>
                                    <p><? echo $term->description; ?></p>
                                    <a href="?tags=<? echo $term->slug; ?>" class="btn hvr-bounce-to-right">View Work</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <? } ?>

            <? } ?>
```

Comment: You haven't passed a tag ID to that function...it has no way of knowing what tag description you want.

Comment: i need to it to work for all child tags of the parent tag 26

Answer (score 0):

Please try this for "tag description".

```
 <?php

  $tags = get_tags();

  foreach ( $tags as $tag ) 
 {
    echo '<pre>';
   //print_r($tag);
    echo $tag_name=$tag->name.'<br>';
    echo $tag_desc=$tag->description.'<br>';   

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed this structure and I solved it like this.

```
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name;
        echo $tag->description;
    }
}
```